# Docker registry mirror for Microsoft images is not working

Tags: docker, .net-core, registry, mirror

I follow the instruction at https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/ to setup 2 registry mirrors for testing purpose.

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  docker-hub:
    image: registry:2.6.2
    ports:
     - "5002:5000"
    volumes:
     - ./registry/conf/docker-hub-mirror-config.yml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml

  mcr:
    image: registry:2.6.2
    ports:
     - "5003:5000"
    volumes:
     - ./registry/conf/mcr-mirror-config.yml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml
```

where `docker-hub-mirror-config.yml` and `mcr-mirror-config.yml` are similar and look like this:

```
version: 0.1

# other fields omitted

proxy:
  remoteurl: https://registry-1.docker.io
```

and

```
version: 0.1

# other fields omitted

proxy:
  remoteurl: https://mcr.microsoft.com
```

Docker Daemon in my host machine:

[image]

When I do `docker pull alpine`, `alpine` image appears in `docker-hub` mirror.

[image]

However when I do `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-alpine`, the image doesn't appear in `mcr` mirror

[image]

Does anyone know what's wrong with my `mcr` registry mirror setup? I can't find much information about `mcr` registry online but when navigating to `https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/_catalog`, it does list the images available

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62148876/4480139